# How to add page border to word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, border, office-interop

I want to add a page border to word document.this is my code

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section sectio in document.Sections)
{
    //Get the header range and add the header details.
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Border border = sectio.Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal];
    border.Visible = true;
    border.Application.ActiveDocument.Activate();
}
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You are not saying if you are having an issue or if you just want congratulations.

Comment: No, this code is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set style, width and color for borders

If I try to set it via VBA, I write code like this

```
With Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
        .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
        .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
        .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an solution based on https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Doc/

```
//initialize an instance
Document document = new Document();
//load a document
document.LoadFromFile(@"Example.docx");
Section section = document.Sections[0];
//add page borders with special style and color
section.PageSetup.Borders.BorderType = BorderStyle.DoubleWave;
section.PageSetup.Borders.Color = Color.LightSeaGreen;
//set the spaces between border and text
section.PageSetup.Borders.Left.Space = 50;
section.PageSetup.Borders.Right.Space = 50;
//save
document.SaveToFile("PageBorders.docx", FileFormat.Docx);
```